# Migrating from Flash CS5 to CS5.5, now having a strange Error

Tags: actionscript-3, migration, flash-cs5, flash-cs5.5, verifyerror

I migrated from CS5 to CS5.5 (on SnowLeopard). I wanted to make some changes on a small project (really simple), but even when I try to test the file without changes I get the following error:

```
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of createGeometry in flashx.textLayout.elements.FlowGroupElement.
```

I never active call the FlowGroupElement, so I got absolutely no clue what is going on.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Same error here. Do you already know how to solve it?